# Windows environment variables not working in cmd

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I just found that i cannot run most commands in windows cmd, such as "git", "java", "node".

I found a lots of answers telling me to set environment variables, the weird thing is, the environment variables looks good to me, and i can actually run these commands in powershell or git bash, but none of them works in windows cmd.

Hope anyone can give me some advise, thank q

Answer (score 1):

As I understand,you are not able to run several commands in windows cmd.

Windows PowerShell is the new Microsoft shell that combines the old cmd functionality with a new scripting/cmdlet instruction set with built-in system administration functionality, so there would be several commands which would work in PowerShell but not in Command Prompt.

Use setx.exe to set persistent environment variables via Command Prompt using following command -

```
 setx [variable_name] "[variable_value]"
```

Please note, setx.exe does not set the environment variable in the current command prompt, but it will be available in subsequent command prompts.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
But i am not able to execute `setx` command in cmd.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
But i am even not able to execute `setx` command in cmd. Besides, `ping`, `ipconfig` and other commonly used commands are also unable to use, which seems like my cmd is totally broken now. The only commands i can run in cmd are some basic commands such as `cd` and `dir`.
I also follow some solutions online which told me to set `c:\Windows\System32` to variable `PATH` to enable commands like `ping` and `ipconfig` in cmd, but when i check the env variables, it was already set, but again i cannot run `ping` in cmd. I am totally confused right now...

Comment: And also, everything works fine until one day i found all the commonly used commands just can't work, but i can't remember what i have done to my pc which leads to this situation...